# Flipping Names in a cell based on a criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of Names in Column R Personal Names & Organization Names. Personal Names are in the format (First name Last name).  In Column Q the type is of name is mentioned (Personal or Organization). Only for Personal names, i want to flip the Personal name in the format (last name first name) in column U. I did a code for this. But somewhere i missing a logic. Can someone help? Thanks

```
    Sub Nameflip()
'
' Nameflip Macro
'

'
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim myformula As String

    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ORD_CS")

    With sht
        LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
        myformula = "=Right(R2, Len(R2) - Find("" "", R2)) & "" "" & Left(R2, Find("" "", R2) - 1)"

        For i = 2 To LR
            If .Range("Q" & i).Value = "P" Then
               .Range("U" & i) = Application.Evaluate(myformula)
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the split function instead, as it's easier to read than your formula:

```
Sub Nameflip()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim vSplit As Variant

    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ORD_CS")
    With sht
        LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To LR
            If CStr(.Range("Q" & i).Value) = "P" Then
               .Range("U" & i) = Split(CStr(.Range("R" & i)))(1) & ", " & Split(CStr(.Range("R" & i)))(0)
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

I assumed the full name source was in column R so you may have to tweak the column letters a bit.

Comment: Thanks much. I tried your split function code, but am getting run time error 13, Type Mismacth for the line - If Range("Q" & i) = "P" Then

Comment: The full Name source is in column R

Comment: Thanks again. But its still showing the same error :(

Comment: Sub Nameflip1()
'
' Nameflip1
'

'
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim vSplit As Variant

    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ORD_CS")
    With sht
        LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "N").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To LR
            If Range("Q" & i).Value = "P" Then
               Range("U" & i) = Split(Range("R" & i))(1) & ", " & Split(Range("R" & i))(0)
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

Comment: Have'nt changed anything, but still i get the error :(

Comment: OK I changed it again.